# List<? super B> lsb = new ArrayList<A>(); Logical error in java?

Tags: java, generics, list, arraylist, wildcard

We have:

```
class A{}
class B extends A{}
class C extends B{}
class D extends C{}
```

we can define Lists like:

```
List<? super B> lsb1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
//List<? super B> lsb2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();//Integer, we expect this    
List<? super B> lsb3 = new ArrayList<A>();
List<? super B> lsb4 = new ArrayList<B>();
//List<? super B> lsb5 = new ArrayList<C>();//not compile
//List<? super B> lsb6 = new ArrayList<D>();//not compile
```

now we crate some objects:

```
Object o = new Object();
Integer i = new Integer(3);
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
C c = new C();
D d = new D();
```

I will try to add this objects to List:

```
List<? super B> lsb = new ArrayList<A>();
lsb.add(o);//not compile
lsb.add(i);//not compile 
lsb.add(a);//not compile
lsb.add(b);
lsb.add(c);
lsb.add(d);
```

Question:

Why when I define reference for `List<? super B>` can I use `new ArrayList<>();` which can have elements type of **B, A, Object** (I expected this), but when I add elements to this list can I add only objects with type **B, C, D**?

Answer (score 5):

Explained beautifully [here @ JavaRanch FAQs](http://faq.javaranch.com/java/GenericsSuperAndExtends).

Comment: +1 for the link, and yes, really explained beautifully there!

Answer (score 4):

A `List<? super B>` is a `List`, whose exact component type is unknown. All the compiler knows is that the component type is `B`, `A` or `Object`.

It could be a `List<B>`.

If it is a `List<B>`, you cannot add an element `A`.

This is to prevent the following, which can happen with arrays:

```
String[] x = new String[10];
Object[] x2 = x;
x2[0] = 123; // not a String, compiles, but crashes at run-time
```